# Generate Keychain IBM Mobile First V 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using IBM Mobile First V 7.1 on an iOS app, the problem is after my app is submitted to the store, Fabric starts to send me weird exception:

> Fatal Exception: Unable to generate key pair. Keychain returned the
>   following status: -25308

and every time I check Crashlytics I see a different trace stack of the exception, and the below is one of the exception that I got:

```
Fatal Exception: Unable to generate key pair.
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18db1d1b8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18c55455c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18db1d100 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  RTA                            0x1012ba4a0 +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:]
4  RTA                            0x1012be730 +[WLCertManager signJWSPartsWithPayload:withPrivateKeyLabel:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:]
5  RTA                            0x10129ffcc -[WLAuthorizationManager buildJWSPartsWithClientId:]
6  RTA                            0x10128607c __71-[WLRequest addClientInstanceIdHeaderWithRequest:withCompetionHandler:]_block_invoke
7  RTA                            0x10129b4ec -[WLAuthorizationManager clientInstanceIdWithCompletionHandler:]
8  RTA                            0x101285f2c -[WLRequest addClientInstanceIdHeaderWithRequest:withCompetionHandler:]
9  RTA                            0x101284f40 -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]
10 RTA                            0x10128685c -[WLRequest makeRequest:withOptions:withCallback:]
11 RTA                            0x1012862f4 -[WLRequest makeRequest:withOptions:]
12 RTA                            0x1012c36e8 -[WLClient invokeProcedure:withDelegate:options:]
13 RTA                            0x1002e8d60 specialized FavouritesModel.getFavouritesList(FavouritesRequestDelegate?) -> () (FavouritesModel.swift)
14 RTA                            0x1002e8484 FavouritesModel.getFavouritesList(FavouritesRequestDelegate?) -> () (FavouritesModel.swift:21)
15 RTA                            0x10037508c MainDashboardViewController.pullToRefreshAction() -> () (MainDashboardViewController.swift:1793)
16 RTA                            0x100389dc8 partial apply for MainDashboardViewController.(upperViewAnimation() -> ()).(closure #2).(closure #4) (MainDashboardViewController.swift:614)
17 Foundation                     0x18e61a46c __NSFireDelayedPerform
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18dacb1d8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18dacaeec __CFRunLoopDoTimer
20 CoreFoundation                 0x18daca7a8 __CFRunLoopDoTimers
21 CoreFoundation                 0x18dac83a4 __CFRunLoopRun
22 CoreFoundation                 0x18d9f62b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
23 GraphicsServices               0x18f4aa198 GSEventRunModal
24 UIKit                          0x193a3d7fc -[UIApplication _run]
25 UIKit                          0x193a38534 UIApplicationMain
26 RTA                            0x100913fe0 main (AppDelegate.swift:35)
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x18c9d95b8 (Missing)
```

After some investigation and searching I found some recommendation to enable Keychain Sharing and the below screenshot is my app entitlement:

[image: Entitlement]

Please any advise how I can solve this problem or is there any missing configuration should be applied

Comment: Is this issue on iOS 10? And after enabling keychain sharing, it is working?

Comment: Yes most crashes depend on Fabric are on iOS 10, but after enabling keychain sharing we still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal Exception: Unable to generate key pair. Keychain returned the
>   following status: -25308

The above error occurs when app tries to generate key pair while phone is locked or while app is running during background mode.  It seems to be your app is doing MFP requests while app is background or phone is locked.

Currently Mobilefirst iOS 7.x Client SDK's do not support MFP requests running in the background. You can use non-MFP API's if you are accessing unsecured resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to ask if there is any way to cancel MFP request if the app goes into background

Comment: @ammararangy Based on the error, Your app is initiating MFP requests in background mode itself. Put one condition to check app is in foreground mode before doing MFP request.

Comment: Aha this situation can be handled, but does this issue could happen if the app request MFP request in foreground and then user put the app to background

Comment: @ammararangy I don't think there will be a CRASH as this issue happens only while accessing keychain. MFP API access keychain first and then makes requests. So, if keychain accessed in foreground and then if app goes to background - the request will pass through without any error. But still its worth testing.